# Trying to show multiple categories in variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used -

```
<?php the_category( ' & ' ); ?>
```

to show multiple categories in the format -ie; General News & Featured

I am trying to add this as a variable and can get just one category to output, but no more, even if the post is in multiple categories.

The existing code I have is -

```
$post_category = get_the_category();

$html .= '<p>Posted in' . $post_category[0]->cat_name . '</p>';
```

How can I get this to output as something like - Posted in General News & Featured

thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the *get_the_category_list()* function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list

Comment: Tried that. Just throws an error for me inside the variable